# sum of the largest and smallest prime factors

Tags: prime-numbers

I got different answer from the answer sheet which says the answer is 14. What is the easiest way to find the largest prime factors of 5445?

> What is the sum of the largest and smallest prime factors of 5445?

Comment: What answer did you get? (14 is correct.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd go about it:

1. $5445$ ends in $5$ so we know that's one prime factor. In fact $5445=5500-55=5(1100-11)=5\cdot1089$
2. If we look at $1089$ and add up the digits, we have $1+0+8+9=2\cdot9$. We can use the fact that the sum of a numbers digits are divisible by $9$ iff the number is too. So $1089=999+90=9\cdot(111+10)=9\cdot121$. Recall that $9=3^2$ so we've just found two more factors.
3. Looking at $121$ we can recall that it's $11^2$

So we can factor $5445$ as $5\cdot3^2\cdot11^2$. So our answer's $3+11=14$.